# maps application - best way to store co-ordinates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, geolocation

I'm making a maps application. I have the co-ordinates of a bunch of locations. I want to return all the points within the area visible on the screen. This is done with the google maps api. It gives you the north-east and south-west co-ordinates of the map visible on the screen. I'm using MongoDb.

The obvious way is to take the midpoint of the ne-sw diagonal as the center, its distance from either corner as the radius, and find all points within that radius.

But storing them in a single list would be a O(n) operation - not scalable to do for every request. What would be a better way of storing them to be able to get the points quickly?

I'm thinking of splitting them into buckets that contain all points within radius(r), and maintain a sorted list of buckets instead. Since the screen can be on 4 buckets at-most (every corner on a separate bucket), I find the closest bucket in O(log n) and the next 3 closest ones in O(1). Now I have to do computations only for these 4 buckets.

But that's are still a LOT of buckets! Google is able to render points on a map VERY quickly. And they have a LOT of points. And a LOT of users. How do they manage that? I don't expect to reach that level of optimization, but there's got to be a better data structure.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I’m not understanding…. Your solution sounds pretty complicated..

You have the screen corners  - NE Long and Lat and SW Long and Lat 
Therefore you have SW_Lat, SW_long, NE_lat, SW_Lat

You want to select the points within this boundary…
If you have your long & lat stored as decimal use a pseudo code of :

```
Select * from points 
where point_lat > SW_lat 
and point_lat < NE_lat
and point_long > SW_long
and point_long < NE_long
```

That will fill the visible screen.